# Use current selected file in finder with Alfred.app?

Tags: macos, finder

I really use Alfred a lot. I now was just wondering if I can do somethings with the currently selected file in finder (most of the time move it to a folder, create new mail with this as attachment, open with application xyz etc pp). I think Launchbar and Quicksilver had such a feature.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Alfred is not AppleScriptable, and I didn't find a built-in function or additional hotkey.

Comment: You're right, LaunchBar does have a feature that does this, called ["Instant Send"](http://www.obdev.at/resources/launchbar/help/InstantSend.html). (Sorry I don't have an Alfred answer for you.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed there is.

1. Select the file in Finder
2. Hold down `Command + shift + G`

This shortcut can be altered if necessary:

- For Version 1: *Preferences » Features » File Navigation*.
- For Version 2: *Preferences » Features » File Search » Actions » File Selection*

[image: Version 1 Preferences Screen Shot]

The available actions for the selected file then shows in Alfred. This is at the moment an 
advanced feature and thus requires the Powerpack (12 pounds).

[image: Version 1 Act Upon File Screen Shot]

Comment: The layout has now changed. It's available under *Features > File Search > Actions* at the bottom: *File Selection*.

Answer (score 5):

If others search for how to get the selected files as input in an Alfred 2 workflow, you can add a hotkey trigger where the argument is set to "Selection in OS X":

[image]

It works with files selected in Finder, Alfred, and other applications. If multiple files are selected, their paths are separated by tabs in `{query}`. This method can also be used to get plain text selections as input, but there is currently no way to replace the selected text like in Automator.

Answer (score 3):

You can also select the file/folder in Finder, then invoke Alfred, type actions and hit return:

[image: example of Alfred action list for selected Finder item]

Comment: This option doesn't appear in v2 of Alfred. Any work arounds beside a hotkey?

Comment: For the record, in v2 this feature is in Features > File Search > Actions > File Selection.

Comment: @Form Still only has a hotkey option there.